# How can I use a mask for a textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I use a mask for the textbox?

I am using Guna2 framework and there is no MaskedTextBox there.

You need to make a mask manually. I tried some options from the internet, but they didn't work.

Before that, I tried handling keyboard presses and separating with dots after every 2 characters. But this is a bad way. Who knows how to do it using DateTime or other methods?

```
    private void guna2TextBox20_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        guna2TextBox20.Text = GetMaskedString("dd.MM/yyyy",guna2TextBox20.Text);
    }
    public static string GetMaskedString(string mask, string input)
    {
        try
        {
            MaskedTextProvider provider = new MaskedTextProvider(mask);
            provider.Add(input);
            return provider.ToDisplayString();
        }
        catch { return input; }
    }
```

I've tried this. Works, but enters the date backwards

```
    private void guna2TextBox20_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MaskedTextBox mask = new MaskedTextBox();
        mask.Mask = "00/00/0000";
        mask.Text = guna2TextBox20.Text;
        guna2TextBox20.Text = mask.Text;
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not an image.  It is not possible to copy past code out of an image for testing in order to try and help you.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith yes. sure

Answer (score 1):

Just add a [MaskedTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox?view=net-5.0) control to your form and put its visibility to false.

It  would create a mapping system which your MaskedTextProvider would be using

MaskedTextBox control is a part of Windows Forms and should be available in the Toolbox like in this [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5TZV.png)

Comment: 'private void guna2TextBox20_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MaskedTextProvider maskedText = new MaskedTextProvider("dd/MM/yyyy");
            maskedText.Set(guna2TextBox20.Text);
            guna2TextBox20.Text = maskedText.ToDisplayString();
        }'

There is no MaskedTextBox in the Guna library. I added winforms. Here is my code. If I'm doing something wrong, please tell me

Comment: You don't have it in Guna library, 

it is in windows form, just open Toolbox in visual studio and search for MaskedTextBox among windows controllers, and add it to the form, your code is correct.

Check out the image I added to the answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Roozbeh The standard properties do not contain the design settings I need. Therefore, I am using the framework

Comment: You can use the framework, however when you add MaskedTextBox then you can use the masking mapping system, you can add this control, hide it (visible false) and then use the the framework you are using